# ArcGIS Online - Access Organization Resource Programmatically OpenID Connect Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Big picture intent: We have a user in our database, ArcGIS has a user in their database. ArcGIS knows that this user is in our database and can authenticate using OpenID Connect, they even have our user's ID. Our user should be able to log into our app, navigate to a map (that requires authentication to load), then behind the scenes we authorize this user with ArcGIS and show the map.

We have set up the ability for users to sign in to ArcGIS Online via our Identity Provider using OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 as described by [this documentation](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/openid-connect-logins.htm). This is working well. Now the question is how can we pass the token for our authorized user to ArcGIS to access a protected resource such as a FeatureLayer? To clarify, the ArcGIS Online member of our Organization is authenticated via OpenID Connect and, in the same way that this user can access ArcGIS Online, we want him/her to be able to access a resource from our ArcGIS Organization from our app. How can this be accomplished or can someone point us in the direction of some documentation for this? Following is the expected flow:

[image]

1. From our application, a user requests an access token from our internal
   Identity Provider built on IdentityServer4 (using OpenID Connect and
   OAuth 2.0) [this is already done]
2. The Identity Provider authenticates the user and returns an access token [done]
3. From our app, a user attempts to load a map using a FeatureLayer belonging to our Organization, which triggers a resource
   request (we are using `@arcgis/core`, see technical details in the code below) for that FeatureLayer to our ArcGIS Organization, passing our access token [how to
   pass our token in this case?]
4. ArcGIS sees that this token it contains the user ID for the aforementioned user in their system, which it knows is matched with the OpenID "Authority" (specified by
   the setup described in the link above), so ArcGIS verifies this
   token with the OpenID "Authority"
5. Our Identity Provider responds that the token is valid
6. ArcGIS trusts the user and returns the resource

This same question on [ArcGIS Online Questions](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/access-organization-resource-programmatically/m-p/1164610#M45600).

Edit: Here is an example of what we would do if we had a user who logged in with their Esri credentials:

```
var tokenProps = {
    server: "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/authorize", // Instead point this to our IdentityProvider?
    userId: "",
    token: token, // Instead use our token?
    ssl: true,
    expires: 7200
}
IdentityManager.registerToken(tokenProps)

const map = new Map({ basemap: "streets-night-vector" })

const trailheadsLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: `https://services1.arcgis.com/OHAG7qgFBy3zKabU/arcgis/rest/services/COVID_Trends/FeatureServer`,
    renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
        symbol: new PictureMarkerSymbol({
            url: "http://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/NPS/npsPictograph_0231b.png",
            width: "18px",
            height: "18px"
        })
    }),
    labelingInfo: [
        new LabelClass({
            labelPlacement: "above-center",
            labelExpressionInfo: {
                expression: "$feature.TRL_NAME"
            },
            symbol: new TextSymbol({
                color: "#fff",
                haloColor: "#5e8d74",
                haloSize: "2px",
                font: {
                    size: "12px",
                    family: "Noto Sans",
                    style: "italic",
                    weight: "normal"
                }
            })
        })
    ]
})
map.add(trailheadsLayer)

new MapView({
    center: [-118.805, 34.007],
    container: mapId,
    map,
    zoom: 13
})
```

However, we need to use the token from our Identity Provider. How can this be accomplished? We have tried using `IdentityManager.registerToken(tokenProps)` where token props contains our token and `server=identityprovider.novotx.dev` but this does not result in us bypassing the login popup once the map using the FeatureLayer is loaded.

To clarify, my question is not how to send a bearer token to ArcGIS but specifically how to exchange a token from our internal Identity Provider with either a resource directly, or for an Esri/ArcGIS access token. This must be possible because, as shown in the documentation above, a user can gain access to ArcGIS online via our internal Identity Provider.

Comment: You need to elaborate on Step 3 - is this an HTTP request, is this a web page request that then issues an API request,

Comment: @DeltaGeorge thanks for your feedback, I've updated my question to elaborate on step 3 and provider further clarification at the end

Comment: Thank you, @Joshua Abbott. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

According to ArcGIS API for JavaScript, registerToken is to provide an existing token to access an ArcGIS server. Based on this, I would expect the server property to indicate what ArcGIS server is to be accessed, e.g. https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest

Presumably the task of making sense of the token is up to that server which has been previously configured with an external IdP urls.

Comment: I see what you're saying here, and I wish it was as easy as setting `sever="https://my-organization.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/authorize"`. When trying to load the map this still prompts to sign in. The goal is to bypass the login prompt all together since a trust has already been established between ArcGIS and our IdP for this user.

Comment: Maybe registering a token is causing an issue in the first place? This does not seem to match any OAuth2 flows. SSO should take care of this without asking for a login.

Comment: If I skip registering the token, it acts the same (prompts for login, even every time the map is shown). Somehow I need to get this token that was given to me by the internal identity provider and give it to ArcGIS/Esri so that they know who the user is.

Comment: Have you selected the option to include the access token in the header?

Comment: Make user auto-registration enabled or the OIDC user registered

Comment: Yes, tokens in the header, and yes the OIDC user is registered with ArcGIS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243936/discussion-between-joshua-abbott-and-delta-george).